# Multitasking Pattern for One Collector and Multiple Generators

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, multitasking

Environment: .NET 4.0 C#

I have multiple running generators async. They generate `IResult` object, check common criteria and push result to shared collection. Generators have to support cancellation and progress reports.

Here is a pseudo code:

```
private Dictionary<string, IResult> resultCollection;
private ICriteria criteria;
private bool isCancelled;

// Multiple Running Generators
private GeneratingAsync(ICriteria criteria)
{
    while (!isCancelled)
    {
        IResult result = GenerateResultAsync();

        if (CheckCriteria(result, criteria))
            OnResultAvailable(this, new ResultEventArgs(result));
        OnProgressChanged(this, new ProgressEventArgs(...));
    }
}

private void OnResultAvailable(object sender, ResultEventArgs e)
{
    // Push result object
    if(!resiltCollection.Contains(e.Id))
        resiltCollection.Add(e.Id, e.Result)
    ...
}

private void OnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

In my current project I use one Generator implemented with BackGroundWorker. My question is what pattern to use for multiple async generators:

- I read about Observer Design Pattern, but MS recommends it for one generator and multiple observers, which is not my case.
- Event pattern
- Reactive Extensions
- ...

Also, can I use several BackGroundWorkers or it's better to use tasks?

Edit:

What is better for `resultCollection`: ConcurrentDictionary or Dictionary with properly locked `AddResult()` and `GetResult()` methods?

Comment: I don't understand the problem that you are trying to solve. Can you describe more about that rather than how you think it should be solved?

Comment: The problem is that I have to generate multiple objects async. These objects have to fulfill a predefined criteria. Once a object is generated and checked, it must be stored in a collection. So I need several generators to work simultaneously and to push results with cancellation and progress report. Result collection must be thread safe.

Comment: Again, you're describing the solution and not the problem. What are you trying to solve? (Not how are you solving it.)

Comment: @Enigmativity, I want to generate trading strategies for the Forex market.

Comment: I don't want to sound difficult, but that's not really the problem, it's more like a title and not a description.

Comment: I think the class you are looking for is [BlockingCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40340027/2791540), which is essentially a thread-safe queue specialized for producer/consumer.