# c# Blocking Collection and Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, blockingcollection

I'm new to using Blocking Collection and threading and want to make sure I'm following best practice. I'm using a third party API that is not thread safe. I will be making multiple simultaneous requests to the API, so I need to add these requests to a queue and process them one after another. To do this I have a blocking collection:

```
    BlockingCollection<myEventArgs> myTasks = new BlockingCollection<myEventArgs>();

    private void myEventHandler(object sender, myEventArgs e)
    {
        myTasks.Add(e);
    }

    private void doWork()
    {

        while (myTasks.IsCompleted == false)
        {

        //Do some work here with the third party API. 
        var eArgs = myTasks.Take();

        //Sometimes I have a background (thread safe) task to perform.
        //This is submitted to the thread pool.
        Task.Run(() => doSomeBackgroundWork());

        }
    }
```

Sometimes I will have a thread safe background task I want to perform. For example, the API calls are asynchronous and I need to poll the third party system to check if a task is complete. I don't want this to prevent the BlockingCollection from processing the next task, so I submit this to the thread pool. Once the thread pool task is complete it will fire an event, which adds a new task to the BlockingCollection.

Is this solution appropriate & is there anything that could go wrong with this? Am I correct to assume that the doWork method that processes items from the BlockingCollection will always run in the same thread? And when I fire events from the threadpool, only the event will run on the thread pool, and not the subsequent doWork method?

Comment: I think DoWork() needs a loop, inside or around it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, there is a loop, I just paraphrased my code! I'll add it in now for clarity.

Comment: Side note, the standard C# practices call for PascalCasing for methods and types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this solution appropriate

Basically, yes. It is a Producer/Consumer situation and that's precisely what the BlockingCollection is for.

> is there anything that could go wrong with this?

You have to be very sure that the `doSomeBackgroundWork()` is thread-safe with respect to your doWork() code.

It might be a good idea to put a ceiling on Your blockingcollection, dependng on how many myEventArgs can be pushed.

Comment: Great, thanks very much. The doSomeBackgroundWork() method is essentially a SQL select statement to query a third-party job manager. It doesn't update or change anything, so it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but for the sake of readers, I would like to point out, that doing it this way, is the same as just spawning threads without a blocking collection, thus removes the whole point of BlockingCollection.

What would be more appropriate in this case, is to manage the number of threads, and only spawn a specific number of threads, while consuming the BlockingCollection, and that would make sure not too many threads get spawned at the same time

Comment: Yes, like this example uses four threads:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/process-queue-with-multithreading-or-tasks